# Apply scale moves objects

Tags: transforms

I have a set of eyeballs made up of 2 meshes joined together, a pupil and an iris. When I apply rotation and scale, it moves them in different directions. How can I apply rotation, scale etc. without changing an object's transformations? .blend file is below [image]

Comment: you've changed the delta transform values, I don't know how you can deal with that, maybe bring them back to their default values, then move your objects where they are supposed to be, then apply your RotScale

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the wrong file, someone recommended trying that, it was a duplicate file. I edited my post, the .blend file ive attached now  is a copy of the eyes that are attached to my character. I haven't changed any delta values

Comment: yes you did, you just didn't realize, take a look in the Properties panel > Object > Transform > Delta Transform, you need to bring everything back to the default values, it will move, rotate and scale your object so you need to remove and rescale them, then apply everything, I don't know if there's another way

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the *Properties panel > Object > Transform > Delta Transform*, you've accidentally given *Delta Transform* values to your objects. Delta transform is used to move, rotate or scale the objects without affecting their original location, rotation and scale, it can be useful sometimes.

[image]

If you apply the *LocRotScale* of your object, it looks like it applies its *Delta Transform* values as well, but it doesn't reset them, so the object undergoes these *Delta Transform* values again, therefore it may automatically move, rotate or scale, that's what happens here.

I don't know if there's any easy way to fix the issue, as I'm not sure there's any way to apply the *Delta Transform* values alone (?), so you probably need to bring these values back to their default value (0/0/0 - 0/0/0 - 1/1/1), then move, rotate and scale your object to correct its new location, rotation and scale, and at last, apply.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe apply visual transform would do?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thanks..I tried visual transform, it didn't work either. I see what your saying with the delta values. Im not sure when I did this but I followed what you said and reset the values and relocated everything. Applied everything with no problems. Thanks for your help. Just to clarify, the rigging tutorial ive looked at mentions applying location as well as rot +scale... Is that right?

Comment: applying will bring back your object to the center of the scene, so it really depends on why you need to apply location, I don't think it's your goal

Comment: Perfect, copy the delta scale transforms back to transform than set than to 1. Everything will be fine!